# Prefixing entity framework entities in specific scenarios?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm having a specific issue where I have only 1 database to use for both my testing and my production environment.

So is there any way that I can have Visual Studio prefix all my entities in Entity Framework when I'm running it under a specific project/build configuration?

**Edit**
It should be noted that I want to prefix the tablenames, not the entities themselves.

Comment: What do you want to prefix? The table names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty unprofessional deployment and soon or later this will bite you to your ass.

Anyway check [Runtime Model Adapter](http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/) for help with retargeting table mapping per deployment.